# SQL : select only first row when there is duplicate data in group

Tags: sql

How to select only one row data in each different group when I'm using `sum` with `group by`?

I would like to remove the second row and show only first row and third row.

This is my query:

```
SELECT f_provider, SUM(f_rebate_amount) as total_cashback, 
       DATE(f_match_time) as match_time, f_status
FROM rebate_history
GROUP BY f_provider, f_created_time, f_status
```

[image]

Comment: Your query is technically invalid due to `GROUP BY`.  I'm guessing you're using MySQL.  Please tag your question with the actual database, and also include some sample data.

Comment: In group by  you have `f_created_time` . You can replace it with `DATE(f_match_time)`